# How to fit a straight board against bowed drywall

Tags: drywall, woodworking

I've built a 90 degree mantle in 2 pieces out of pine that slides over a "shelf" of 2x4s screwed into the wall. It appears the drywall seriously bows in between the studs, and creates this gap between the mantle and the drywall when running this 8' mantle down the wall.

What are my options to make this look better.. I was figuring:

Easiest - Stain an additional quarter round type trim piece and put it over the top..
Medium - ??
Hardest - Sand or trim away the mantle board to match the bow in the drywall. I already have a weird wall angle cut out of the board, and it would be easy to throw that out of whack.

Thank you for any help.
[image: Picture of the board]

Comment: shim the wood, or fill the gap

Comment: With the easy way, the trim will need to be bent into the wall and probably show if looked at the same way.  The hardest way of trimming the board should hide the bend/curve, but it is the hardest to look right.

Comment: You could also do what granite countertop installers do: cut into the drywall to accommodate the part of the board that needs to go behind the surface. Then cover the joint with caulking

Comment: There’s an old saying in the trade: caulk and paint will make you the carpenter you ain’t.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, measure the biggest gap, then find a small block and notch or drill so that the pencil will be held at that gap size.

Draw the pencil line by holding the block/pencil against the wall and follow the shape of the wall.

Remove the shelf and trim to the line - either bow saw or jig saw. Then fit and seal as needed.

Comment: Or just set a compass to the correct spacing and drag it along the wall to make the line. The technique is called "scribing."

Comment: THank you for your answer, that seems to make the most sense.. It might be worth it to do it first with a template or a cheap board, because I'm that that confident in my jigsaw, or jigsaw skills.  To complicate it, there is an underside of the mantle as well that meets the same wall so I would have to make that same cut twice. I saw a $35 delta scroll saw at the thrift store the other day that I should have picked up.

Comment: @Ben, as noted, this is called "scribing". If you go to the _This Old House_ web site and search for that term, you'll likely find _dozens_ of video clips showing how it's done. It's very easy, it just takes some patience.